# How to reset input fields which are not form fields in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on the project, where the user provides a number/dateAndMonth/year as input value and accordingly it returns some information about the input which the help of API (www.numbersapi.com).

The code consists of components where the state is defined and its values are are sent as props to re-render the components.

Whenever the 'categoryValue' changes the 'NumbersFactsInput' re-renders.

And whenever the submit button is clicked it fetches the data with help of API.

I want input fields to reset everytime after the 'categoryValue' changes or when the submit button is pressed.

These are state varaibles...

```
class NumberFacts extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            categoryValue : 'trivia',
            number : ' ',
            date : ' ',
            year : ' ',
            displayText : 'Result will appear here!'
        }
    }

onChangeCategory = (event) => {
 this.setState({categoryValue : event.target.value}) ;
}
```

This is my submitButton function...

```
 onButtonClick = (event) => {

        switch(this.state.categoryValue) {
            case 'trivia' : this.fetchData(this.state.number);
                                break;

            case 'math' : this.fetchData(this.state.number);
                                break;

            case 'date' : this.fetchData(this.state.date);
                                break;

            case 'year' : this.fetchData(this.state.year);
                                break;  

            default : console.log('default case');
        }
 }
```

My render function, from where I am sending props to other components...

```
render() {
        return(
        <div className='tc bg-light-blue dib br3 pa3 ma3 bw2 shadow-5'>
        <h1>Number Facts</h1>
        <NuberFactsCategories  changeCategory = {this.onChangeCategory} />
        <NumberFactsInputs category={this.state.categoryValue} inputChange={this.onInputChange} />
        <DisplayText text={this.state.displayText}/>
        <SubmitButton buttonClick={this.onButtonClick} />
        </div>
        );
        }
```

Ans this is my input field component...

```
const NumberFactsInputs = ({ category, inputChange }) => {

    if(category === 'trivia' || category === 'math') {
    return(
            <div>
            <ul onChange={inputChange}>
              <li> <input  className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' type='number' placeholder='Number' /></li>
              <li> <input readOnly className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' type='number' placeholder='MM/DD' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
              <li> <input readOnly className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' type='number' placeholder='YYYY' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        );
   }

    else if(category === 'date') {
     return(
            <div>
            <ul  onChange={inputChange}>
              <li> <input readOnly className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' type='number' placeholder='Number' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
              <li> <input className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' type='text' placeholder='MM/DD' /></li>
              <li> <input readOnly className='br3 dib pa1 ma2 bg-lightest-blue bn' type='number' placeholder='YYYY' style={{opacity: 0.4}}/></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're describing is called [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

In order to change the state of a parent component, you need to pass a setter function to the child component - so it can modify the parent's state, followed by its own value:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fieldValue: 'initial value',
    };
  }

  setFieldValue(newValue) {
    this.setState({
      fieldValue: newValue,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ControlledChild
        value={this.state.fieldValue}
        onChange={this.setFieldValue.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}

class ControlledChild extends Component {
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```